# What is the difference between ないんですか and んじゃないですか?

Tags: meaning, negation, particle-か

Do they both mean "is it not/isn't it"?

e.g. Do この車は新しく**ないんですか** and この車は新しい**んじゃないですか** both mean ”Isn’t this car new?”？

Answer (score 2):

Both can be a negative rhetorical question, but are used in different situations.

この車は新しくないんですか is "Isn't this car new?" It sounds like they are talking about the age of one specific car. More literally, "As for this car, isn't it new?"

この車は新しいんじゃないですか is "Isn't this one a new car?" It sounds like they are finding a new car among many cars. More literally, "*This* car is new, isn't that right?"